# how to remove a parameter in a system of parametric equations?

Tags: sympy

I know that the following system of parametric equations

```
x = cos(t)
y = sin(t)
```

can be simplified with a trig identity to eliminate the t parameter and provide the implicit equation `x^2 + y^2 = 1` for the unit circle.

Is it possible to do this kind of simplification in SymPy?